# Method with try catch and exception throws

Tags: c++, loops, types, try-catch

So I have the following method:

```
template <class DT> //needs testing
DT& LinkedSortedArrays<DT>::find (const DT& key)
{
    list<SortedArray<DT>>::iterator it = SAList.begin();
    for( ; it != SAList.end(); ++it){
        try{
            if (it == SAList.begin() && key < (*it)[0]) throw Exception();
            return (*it).find(const_cast<DT&> (key));
        } catch (ArrayException e) {

        }
    }
    throw Exception();
}
```

I have previously defined the classes `Exception` and `ArrayException`. `(*it).find(const_cast<DT&> (key))` will throw a ArrayException everytime that `key` is not found in the specific Array class being searched at the moment. `SAList` is a `STL List`. The code compiles just fine. However I haven't tried it in my program. Why? I need somebody to confirm or correct me on the following assumptions I have done:

1. Whenever `if (it == SAList.begin() && key < (*it)[0]) throw Exception();` throws an exception, it means it will throw it outside the for loop and even outside the method, right?
2. I am almost sure that the last line `throw Exception();` will throw the Exception outside the method.
3. The way the for loop is arranged, it won't skip the first element of SAList, right? I mean, I have seen this specific code all over the internet that serves to iterate through all elements of the list as if it was standard or flawless, but... that `++it` is twisting my brain. Help?
4. I was receiving an error of `can't convert const int to int&` (since the `find()` in `(*it).find(const_cast<DT&> (key))` is not the one belonging to `LinkedSortedArrays` but rather a different one that requires a DT& variable and `LinkedSortedArrays`'s `find()` has parameters of type const DT&) and I found that a possible solution might be writing it as `const_cast<DT&> (key)`. I need a second opinion on this.

Lastly, I understand if this is not a specific question and therefore I get downvotes and/or the question gets closed. I simply don't really know where else to ask.
If it is the case that I am asking in the wrong place. My apologies.

Comment: Why doesn't `find` take its parameter by const reference?

Comment: Profesor wants it that way :/
It basically is a `find` belonging to another class, which altogether with `LinkedSortedArrays` make the data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, it will go up the stack until it finds the appropriate `catch` handler. If it finds no such handler, the program will terminate.
2. Yes it will.
3. No, it will not, since `end` should return an iterator to one past the end, not the last element. Unless that container is badly designed as well, but  you'll have to consult the documentation to be sure.
4. That's a bad design, `find` should take its parameter by `const` reference. Since you can't, you'll have to make a copy unless you want to risk undefined behaviour:

   ```
   DT nonconstkey = key;
   return it->find(nonconstkey);
   ```

Comment: What assumptions are you making about the relationship between `ArrayException` and `Exception`?

Comment: Yes, I know, I am very aware of the need of copies. Fortunately for now I am only working with `int`s. So there isn't much of a headache for now.

Comment: @MooingDuck only that `Exception` is not a subclass of `ArrayException`.

Comment: I forgot to mention but, `ArrayException` is a child class of `Exception`

Comment: @Yokhen that's fine, it doesn't change the answer.

Comment: @SethCarnegie Even with `int`s only? I don't understand too well why.

Comment: @Yokhen because the `find` method does not take a `const DT&`, so you need to pass it a `DT&`. `key` is `const`, and you should avoid `const_cast` at almost all costs because if `find` modifies the argument (which it should, because it's not `const`) then you have UB if `key` is really a `const` object.